# Script only prints out final entry instead of removing duplicates

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that's supposed to remove duplicate entries. Some people in the data have entered in their name twice because they have two phone numbers, and because the phone number field was not an array, to enter multiple, they entered multiple entries.

My script changes the entries to dictionaries with keys corresponding to the column names and then goes through each of the rows.  There is a master for loop that goes through each row, and then a nested for loop that runs through all the elements for each element, comparing them to detect duplicates. When I hit a duplicate, my code is supposed to compare the phone, email, and websites and then append them to an area if they are unique / don't match.

The script runs, but the csv it returns is filled with the last person in the csv repeated 8 times and nothing else.

Here's my code:

```
import csv

# This function takes a tab-delim csv and merges the ones with the same name but different phone / email / websites.
def merge_duplicates(sheet):

    myjson = [] # myjson = list of dictionaries where each dictionary

    with(open("ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt", "rU")) as f:

        sheet = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter="\t")
        for row in sheet:
            myjson.append(row)

        write_file = csv.DictWriter(open('duplicates_deleted.csv','w'), ['name','phone','email','website'], restval='', delimiter = '\t')

        for row in myjson:

            # convert phone, email, and web to lists so that extra can be appended
            row['phone'] = row['phone'].split() if row.get('phone') else []
            row['email'] = row['email'].split() if row.get('email') else []
            row['website'] = row['website'].split() if row.get('website') else []
            print row

        i = 0

        for i in range(len(myjson)):

            # if the names match, check to see if phone, em, web match. If any match, append to first row.
            try:
                print 'trying'
                if myjson[i]['name'] == myjson[i+1]['name']:
                    if myjson[i]['phone'] != myjson[i+1]['phone']:
                        print 'detected'
                        myjson[i]['phone'].append(myjson[i+1]['phone'])
                    if myjson[i]['email'] != myjson[i+1]['email']:
                        myjson[i]['email'].append(myjson[i+1]['email'])
                    if myjson[i]['website'] != myjson[i+1]['website']:
                        myjson[i]['website'].append(myjson[i+1]['website'])
            except IndexError:
                print("We're at the end now") 

            write_file.writerow(row)
            print row

merge_duplicates('ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt')
```

This is the csv output (not a real person...made up!)

```
"Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.   []  []  []"
"Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.   []  []  []"
"Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.   []  []  []"
"Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.   []  []  []"
"Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.   []  []  []"
"Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.   []  []  []"
"Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.   []  []  []"
"Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.   []  []  []"
```

Thanks so much for the help!

---

Ex data if it helps:

```
name    phone   email   website
Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.           
"Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP"   111-222-3333    cersei@got.com  www.got.com
Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.           
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    000-000-1111    dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    111-222-333     dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
D G Bamf M.S.           
Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.
```

Comment: BTW try to use list comprehension, i.e. myjson = [row for row in csv.DictReader(f,delimiter="\t")] if you intend to pack iterator into the list (eq. to reading rows into memory).

Comment: use elif in if sections for even mutually exclusive cases (garbage-in principle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific problem is that you're writing `row` to your output csv, but you never reassign it after using it in the for loop that builds your list of dictionaries:

```
 write_file.writerow(row)
```

This code is a bit muddled.  I think a simpler approach would be to use an `OrderedDict` by name, assuming you're on 2.7 or later:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict

people = OrderedDict()
with(open("ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt", "rU")) as f:
    sheet = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter="\t")
    for row in sheet:
        name = row.get('name')
        if name:
            contact_information = people.setdefault(name, {})
            contact_information.setdefault('phone', set()).add(row.get('phone'))
            contact_information.setdefault('email', set()).add(row.get('email'))
            contact_information.setdefault('website', set()).add(row.get('website'))

    write_file = csv.DictWriter(open('duplicates_deleted.csv','w'), ['name','phone','email','website'], restval='', delimiter = '\t')
    for name, contact_information in people:
        row_dict = {'name': name}.update({list(contact_field) for contact_field in contact_information.values()})
        write_file.writerow(row_dict)
```

That uses the Python `set` class to keep one copy of each phone number, email address and web site for each unique name, then converts them to lists for pretty writing to your CSV.  It doesn't maintain order - unfortunately there's no built in `OrderedSet`, but you could use another `OrderedDict` instead of a set if you want to preserve the order they were seen in.

Comment: Should I write myjson[i] instead?